# deserializing multiple types with gson

Tags: gson

I receive the following JSON response from my http web service

```
{"status":100,"data":[{"name":"kitchen chair","price":25.99,"description":null}]}
```

Now I want to be able to deserialize this. I stumbled upon Gson from Google, which at first worked well for some small testcases but I'm having some trouble getting the above string deserialized.

I know the `data` field only has one item in it, but it could hold more than one which is why all responses have the `data` field as an array.

I was reading the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and ideally I would like to have a `Response` object which has two attributes: `status` and `data`, but the `data` field would have to be a `List` of `Map` objects which presumably is making it hard for Gson.

I then looked at [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) which is an example closer to my problem but I still can't quite figure it out. In the example the whole response is an array, whereas my JSON string has one string element and then an array.

How would I best go about deserializing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly was already attempted that appeared to be "hard for Gson".

The latest release of Gson handles this simply.  Following is an example.

**input.json**

```
{
    "status":100,
    "data":
    [
        {
            "name":"kitchen chair",
            "price":25.99,
            "description":null
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Response
{
  int status;
  List<Map> data;
}
```

**GsonFoo.java**

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Response response = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Response.class);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(response));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"status":100,"data":[{"name":"kitchen chair","price":25.99}]}
```